# Proper MaterializeCSS initialization in VueJS Project

Tags: vue.js, materialize

I try to init MaterializeCSS framework **without jQuery** in VueJS project, created with npm (`vue init webpack projectname`)

From version `1.0.0-rc.2` Materialize supports its own initialization without jQuery, smth like this:

```
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.collapsible');
    var instances = M.Collapsible.init(elems, options);
  });
```

But with this way, JS Materialize Components work only after manual page
reloading and when I open some component and return to component with Materialize stuff - it doesn't work - I need to reload page manually again all the time.

So how to init JS components in proper way?

Comment: See the question solved:[M is not defined when using Materialize-css with Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51429968/m-is-not-defined-when-using-materialize-css-with-vue/60404496#60404496)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It worked for me so you may want to try this:

Go to your `src/main.js` file and add the following lines (if assume you are using `npm`):

```
import 'materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min'
```

Personally, I use the `M.AutoInit()` way of initializing JS components on each vue component that needs them:

```html
<template>
  <div class="componentName">
    <!-- Some HTML content -->
  </div>
</template>


<script>
  export default {
    name: 'componentName',

    data() {
      return {
        // Some values
      };
    },

    mounted() {
      M.AutoInit(); // That way, it is only initialized when the component is mounted
    }
  }
</script>


<style scoped>
  /* Some CSS */
</style>
```

Using `M.AutoInit()` or

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.collapsible');
    var instances = M.Collapsible.init(elems, options);
  });
```

inside the `mounted` function of your component will result in them being called only when they are fully mounted.

Comment: Why this method doesn't work when I try to use `v-if` and `v-else` construcntions? For example, I fetch data from server and I place my collpsible into `v-else` tag - to show some data in collpasible when it would be received

Comment: v-if and v-else remove the concerned node from the DOM so it is not mounted. The `mounted` method is called when the component is mounted into the DOM so try calling your initialization function in the `created` method instead