# M is not defined when using Materialize-css with Vue

Tags: vuejs2, materialize

I am using Materialize css with Vue. I have installed as an npm module and imported it in main.js

```
import Material from "materialize-css";
import "materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css";
import "materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js";
Vue.use(Material);
```

All the css is working fine, however, whene I try to use any javascript component like materialbox like this

```
const mb = document.querySelectorAll(".materialboxed");
M.MaterialBox.init(mb, {});
```

It gives an error that "M" is not defined. What should I do? I have added materialize-css as a dependency to the package.json.

Comment: Got the same problem, would be interested in the answer.

Comment: @Badgy because materialize-css is not a vue plugin.. I have replied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vue.use is for vue plugins. materialize-css is not a vue plugin. And you dont do stuff like `document.querySelectorAll` in vue. And when you use something like M -> you need to import it first. Please read vue [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/index.html) and understand how it work first.

You should use something like [vue-material](https://github.com/vuematerial/vue-material) or [vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com) for vue, or otherwise if you will try to hack materialize-css to work with vue you end up in not really maintainable code

Answer (score 4):

Add following code in your component(say App.vue):

```
import M from 'materialize-css'

export default {
...
mounted () {
    M.AutoInit()
},
...
```

Comment: Thank you this help me. But this way import Materialize only locale( for one page). And How to import Materialize Global. For all pages in project. Maybe in App.vue or main.js. I don't know. ???

Answer (score 2):

I thought I would provide a different answer based my own experience. I like Materializecss and didn't want to use something else just because it is more tailored towards Vuejs. Materializecss seems to have a larger community and is also used by other people who use things like Reactjs, so I think it is somewhat rational to prefer it over a more niche library.

I use the following in `main.js`:

```
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css'
import 'materialize-css'
```

Also, in `public/index.html`, I have the following for the icons:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
```

For me this seems to work perfectly fine including when I use `M.Toast...` etc. I think the difference is me using `import 'materialize-css'` where you have `import Material from "materialize-css"`.

As a side-note however, I do get ESLint errors when building which says `'M' is not defined` in spite of the code actually working. ESLint just does not know that it is there. To get rid of these, I used the following hacky approach of putting the lines below at the top of the modules where I use materialize:

```
// Get rid of those pesky eslint errors for Materialize-css
if (typeof M == "undefined") {var M = {}}
```

This has the nice effect of showing me where it is used in a similar vein as an `import` statement at the top, but I'm sure there are good reasons why this is actually bad advice.

Answer (score 0):

for `M => error: 'M' is not defined (no-undef) ...`

To prevent the transpiler from swearing - write as in:

```
node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.js => **window.M**
```